# Macro to make std::pair with fixed types

Tags: c++, macros, std-pair

I'm trying to do something like this:

```
#define SOME_PAIR(x, y) std::make_pair<bool, std::string>(x, y)
```

So that what the programmer has to write is simply:

```
return SOME_PAIR(true, "Amazing");
```

But it looks like i'm doing something wrong, as '**no instance of function template "std::make_pair" matches the argument list**'.

What can i do to make this (or something similar to this) work?

Compiler: **VC110**
IDE: **VS2012**
OS: **Win7x64**

**EDIT**: The following code(thanks to **jxh**) makes it work perfectly:

```
#define SOME_PAIR(x, y) std::make_pair(bool(x), std::string(y))
```

And thus my lamda function ends up being really neat:

```
boot.init("log", [&](){
    return INIT_PAIR(log.loaded, "Could not open log config file");
});
```

Comment: Is there something wrong with `std::pair<bool, std::string>(x,y)`? If you're not going to use the template deduction, there really isn't much reason to use `make_pair`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can "cast" the arguments and allow type deduction to instantiate the right template function:

```
#define SOME_PAIR(x, y) std::make_pair(bool(x), std::string(y))
```

Answer (score 0):

The following worked for me.

g++ -std=c+0x -Wall -Wextra pair.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <utility>

#define PAIR(x, y) std::make_pair<bool, std::string>(x, y)

int main(int, char* []) {
  auto p = PAIR(true, "abc");
  std::cout << p.first << " " << p.second << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you forget

```
#include <utility>
```

in the file which invokes the macro?  The compilation is failing at the point where the macro is expanded.

Answer (score 0):

Why you don't use templates for it? It will work for most types (not just bool and string). Something like:

```
#include <iostream>

template<class T1, class T2>
inline std::pair<T1, T2> SOME_PAIR(T1 t1, T2 t2) {
  return std::make_pair(t1, t2);
}

int main() {
  std::pair<bool, std::string> p = SOME_PAIR(true,"hello");

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: The issue I believe he was working on was the fact that `make_pair(true, "some_string")` returns a `std::pair<bool, const char*>`, not a `std::pair<bool, std::string>`.  Your solution doesn't really change that, because it's using the same argument deduction `make_pair` already does.

Comment: You are right, I thought he wanted to change the call name to create a pair... My bad :-p